# Corda Custom Query with field name taken as input

Tags: kotlin, corda

I am using Corda 4.0 and I want to run a custom query with dynamic column name (colN) and column value (colC). Here is my code for the query building

```
builder {
     val index: CriteriaExpression.ColumnPredicateExpression<Any,String> = getField(colN,CarSchemaV1.PersistentCar::class.java).equal(colC)
     val customCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(index)
}
```

But I am getting a error in compile time

```
Type parameter bound for L in constructor VaultCustomQueryCriteria<L: PersistableState>(expression: CriteriaExpression<L,Boolean>,...) is not satisfied: inferred typed Any is not a subtype of StatePersistable
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue here has to do with your use of `Any` in the generics of `CriteriaExpression.ColumnPredicaeExpression<Any, String>`. As indicated by the error message, instead of using `Any` you should be using a subtype of `StatePersistable`

According to the docs: `net.corda.core.schemas.StatePersistable 
Marker interface to denote a persistable Corda state entity that will always have a transaction id and index`

Your schema `CarSchemaV1.PersistentCar::class.java` likely implements PersistentState. Try adding that into your generics.

`val index: CriteriaExpression.ColumnPredicateExpression<CarSchemaV1.PersistentCar,String> = getField(colN,CarSchemaV1.PersistentCar::class.java).equal(colC)`

Comment: That doesn't seems to work since the getField returns `CriteriaExpression.ColumnPredicaeExpression<Any, String> ` and thus cannot be accepted in the index val since it narrows down the type.

Comment: @KaranKulwal did you get any way to do this?